# How To Preserve Changes To Pip Installed Django Apps After Deployment

Tags: django, django-apps

I made custom modification to one of the Django apps in my requirements.txt, the problem is that after deployment I get errors because the I get fresh pip installs from the requirement.txt and the changes I made only work locally. What is the right way to modify pip installed Django apps locally and have those changes also reflect in the deployment environment?

Comment: AFAIR you could use git-repos with pip. `pip install git+https://myserver.org/public/django-registration.git`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could host a fork of the library you want to change somewhere like GitHub, and have your requirements.txt point to that particular change. http://codeinthehole.com/writing/using-pip-and-requirementstxt-to-install-from-the-head-of-a-github-branch/ has a good overview of having a pip requirements file point to a source code repository.